# проблема с подключение клиента к серверу (Java Socket) после контейнеризации Docker

Tags: java, docker, сокет

Сервер прослушивает клиентов на порту `80`, клиент так же подключается к этому порту.
Дальше я создаю два различных образа. Один для сервера, второй для клиента.
В папке где у меня лежит сервер я имею следуюющий `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk
COPY . /java
WORKDIR /java
EXPOSE 80
RUN javac API.java
CMD ["java", "API"]
```

В папке с клиентом `Dockerfile` написан так:

```
FROM openjdk
COPY . /java
WORKDIR /java
EXPOSE 80
RUN javac CLI.java
CMD ["java", "CLI"]
```

Дальше я создаю образы с помощью `docker build .` в каждой папке, и в итоге получаю два образа, один для сервера, второй для клиента.
Следующим шагом я запускаю сервер так:

```
docker run -p 8001:80 id_api_image
```

И у меня сервер запущен, все работает.
Дальше я пытаюсь запустить клиента:

```
docker run -p 8002:80 id_cli_image
```

И здесь я получаю ошибку:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:585)
> at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:507)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:287)
> at CLI.main(CLI.java:9)

Возможно это происходит через то что сервер вообще находится в другом контейнере, поэтому клиент и не может его найти, не знаю. Если и так, тогда как мне решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как все теперь в докере, то серверный порт поменялся. Если можете запустить сервер вот так `docker run -p 80:80 id_api_image`, а вот клиента так `docker run  id_cli_image` - клиенту не нужно открывать порт, значит и не нужно наружу показывать порт. Все должно заработать.

Если же запускаете сервер вот так `docker run -p 8001:80 id_api_image`, то в клиенте в коде нужно поправить порт, на который все будет подключаться. Код клиента нужно будет поправить.

И есть ещё третий вариант - это сделать docker-compose файл или всех добавить в одну сеть вручную.

Если через докер напрямую, то вначале нужно создать сеть https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/

```
docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network
```

(my-bridge-network - это имя созданной сети)

А потом подсказать докеру, что для контейнера нужно использовать эту сеть `--network=my-bridge-network`.

И получается так, сервер:

```
docker run -p 8001:80 --network=my-bridge-network id_api_image
```

клиент

```
docker run --network=my-bridge-network id_cli_image
```

В этом случае порты менять не нужно, а для сервера даже можно удалить `-p 8001:80`, если сервер не будет использоваться за пределами этих двух контейнеров.

Это работает, так как мы вручную указали, что клиент и сервер находятся в одной сети. Правда тут есть одна проблема - это адрес (ip) подключения (адрес самого сервера). Так как теперь у нас это все находится внутри отдельной сети, то и адреса там другие. Я сделал через `docker inspect <id контейнера сервера>` и просто посмотрел его адрес (в виде ip) либо в docker container ps посмотреть id сервера (оно выглядит как 99a38de850af) и использовать его в качестве адреса хоста (хотя у меня есть подозрение, что некоторые приложения будут против)

Если же используете docker-compose, то там это можно сделать автоматически, а имя "сервера" задать самому.

Comment: мне как раз подходит первый вариант. Но в чем может быть еще проблема, если я и дальше получаю ту же ошибку?

Comment: Вы выбрали порт 80? попробуйте подключится к этому серверу через браузер или telnet/netcat и проверьте, работает ли сервер. Разделим проблему на два кусочка.

Comment: В джаве файле сервер ждет клиентов на порту `80`. В джаве файле клиента, тоже подключение к `80` порту. В докер файлах в обоих стоит `EXPOSE 80`. Сервер запускаю так: `docker run -p 80:80 id_api_image`, клиента так: `docker run  id_cli_image`. Если честно я не знаю что такое telnet/netcat, или как подключится к серверу через браузер

Comment: запускаете сервер, открываете браузер на этой же машине, в адресной строке пишите localhost:80/ и ждете. Если сервер отвечает чем-то вменяемым текстовым, Вы это увидите в браузере и в логах сервера.

Comment: сервер работает, и почему то подлючилось сразу два клиента (когда зашел в браузере на `localhost:80`), и как Вы и сказали сервер ответил 'вменяемым текстовым'.

Comment: это нормально. большинство браузеров делает ещё один запрос на favicon.ico. Это уже чудесно. Теперь осталось выяснить, почему не работает клиент. Может он пытается подключится на localhost?

Comment: `Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 80)`, то есть здесь на что нужно поменять?

Comment: да, здесь нужно указать правильный адрес. Скорее всего, если сюда записать ip Вашей машины, то все заработает.

Comment: Теперь, когда я указал правильный `ip` вместо 'localhost' в клиенте - все работает! Спасибо!

Comment: ну да. а можно просто сеть в докере создать и работало бы без изменений. Мне такой способ кажется даже более правильным, но Вам на месте виднее.